# Is there a way to use Laravel's getRoutes() to only return routes that aren't redirects?

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to use Laravel's `Route::getRoutes()` method to generate a dynamic sitemap. The problem is that that method returns routes that are in reality redirects:

Example web.php:

```php
Route::get('not-redirected', function() {
    return view('not-redirected');
}

Route::get('redirected', function() {
    return redirect('was-redirected');
}
```

`Route::getRoutes()` returns `['not-redirected',  'was-redirected']`. Is there a way to dynamically filter out redirected routes from this output?

My desired output for the above `web.php` would be `['not-redirected']`.

EDIT: I've noticed that `php artisan route:list` does not return redirects. However, I can't figure out why just by looking through the source code... It looks like it calls that same function, `Route::getRoutes()`.

Comment: there is no way for it to know what you are returning from your route actions unless it ran them, so you would have to mark the actual route in some particular way, potentially using the action array

Comment: Probably not without static analysis or actually consuming the routes. A Route typically only knows where it is dispatched to, not what happens after dispatching. Perhaps a tool like [spatie/laravel-sitemap](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap) would be useful?

Comment: The action array is tricky to use... There's a redirect property buried deeply in the var_dump but it's impossible to tell where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no way to determine the return for a given route.
The solution I came up with is to add a group all the routes that are 'special',  this way you can easily add custom attributes to a route's action.

```php
Route::group(['return_type' => 'redirect'], function () {
    Route::get('not-redirected', function () {
        return view('not-redirected');
    });

    Route::get('redirected', function () {
        return redirect('was-redirected');
    });
});
```

Then you could loop over the routes like this:

```php
$routes = Route::getRoutes()->get();
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    if ($route->getAction('return_type') === 'redirect') {
        // Or whatever you want to do in this case
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. I think this is a great workaround. One other thing -- I noticed that `php artisan route:list` does not return redirects, but I can't figure out how the redirects are routed out of the code. Do you have any insight into that?

Comment: Regarding the redirects in `artisan route:list`; I just installed a fresh Laravel install and added the routes like in the 1st block, then `route:list` shows both `not-redirected` and `redirected` for me, it's just the `action` that shows as a `Closure` since it's an anonymous function. So if it is really not showing then you might have other issues in your installation that might be worth checking out, or you just need a `artisan route:clear` to flush the cache.